# html div overloads "onmouseup, onkeyup"

Tags: jquery, html, razor

Sorry if using the wrong terminology here.

I know with a div you can apply things like

```
<div onmouseup="doSomething();">
```

Is there a resource anywhere that lists all the types of events you can apply at this level?

or is this literally a jquery thing anything in jquery that's a .on("something can be applied as onsomething() to the dom?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: great thanks a lot  :)

Comment: please do accpet upvote if you got answer you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use: check here  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

```
onclick, ondblclick, onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseout,
    onmouseover, onmouseup, onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup
```

Answer (score 0):

> MouseOut and MouseOver Example

```js
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "64px";
    x.style.width = "64px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "32px";
    x.style.width = "32px";
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
```

**Happy Coding**